# Display video button in CallKit incoming call screen when call is video

Tags: ios, video, callkit, incoming-call

I am using the following code to receive video calls. My application has audio and video call functionality and I am using linphone + CallKit.

```
- (void)config {
    CXProviderConfiguration *config = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc]
                                       initWithLocalizedName:[NSBundle.mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"]];
    config.ringtoneSound = @"notes_of_the_optimistic.caf";

    config.supportsVideo = TRUE;

    config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"callkit_logo"]);


    NSArray *ar = @[ [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)CXHandleTypeGeneric] ];

    NSSet *handleTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:ar];
    [config setSupportedHandleTypes:handleTypes];

    [config setMaximumCallGroups:2];
    [config setMaximumCallsPerCallGroup:1];


    self.provider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:config];
    [self.provider setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}



- (void)reportIncomingCall:(LinphoneCall *) call withUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid handle:(NSString *)handle video:(BOOL)video
{
    CXCallUpdate *update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    update.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:handle];
    update.supportsDTMF = TRUE;
    update.supportsHolding = TRUE;
    update.supportsGrouping = TRUE;
    update.supportsUngrouping = TRUE;
    update.hasVideo = video;
    linphone_call_ref(call);
    // Report incoming call to system
    LOGD(@"CallKit: report new incoming call");

    [self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:uuid
                                          update:update
                                      completion:^(NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              LOGE(@"CallKit: cannot complete incoming call from [%@] caused by [%@]",handle,[error localizedDescription]);
                                              if (   [error code] == CXErrorCodeIncomingCallErrorFilteredByDoNotDisturb
                                                  || [error code] == CXErrorCodeIncomingCallErrorFilteredByBlockList) {
                                                  linphone_call_decline(call,LinphoneReasonBusy); /*to give a chance for other devices to answer*/
                                              } else {
                                                  linphone_call_decline(call,LinphoneReasonUnknown);
                                              }
                                          }
                                          linphone_call_unref(call);
                                      }];
}
```

Please see the attached screenshot of the incoming video call UI. It is displaying the same UI (buttons) for audio and video call. I want to display a video call button when the call is video. Is it possible using CallKit? If it's possible, what changes need to be made? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unfortunately there's no way to customize the CallKit incoming call UI. That's the reason why apps like WhatsApp are using push notifications to notify video calls, instead of relying on CallKit.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this demo. CallKit have a property `supportsVideo` of `CXProviderConfiguration` and one property `hasVideo` of `CXHandle`.
It's working fine for me. Check this below demo link.

https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy

```
func setupVdeoCall() {
        let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App")
        config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "pizza")!)
        config.ringtoneSound = "ringtone.caf"
        config.includesCallsInRecents = false;
        config.supportsVideo = true;
        let provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Pete Za")
        update.hasVideo = true
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: update, completion: { error in })
    }
```

So just modify in `ProviderDelegate.swift` file's like below.

```
    static var providerConfiguration: CXProviderConfiguration {
        let localizedName = NSLocalizedString("CallKitDemo", comment: "Name of application")
        let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: localizedName)

        providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true. //For Video Call Enable
        
        providerConfiguration.includesCallsInRecents = false; //Show hide from phone recent call history
        
        providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1

        providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]

        providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconMask").pngData()

        providerConfiguration.ringtoneSound = "Ringtone.caf"
        
        return providerConfiguration
    }
```

and reportIncomingCall()

```
func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        // Construct a CXCallUpdate describing the incoming call, including the caller.
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
        update.hasVideo = hasVideo //For Video Call available or not

        // pre-heat the AVAudioSession
        //OTAudioDeviceManager.setAudioDevice(OTDefaultAudioDevice.sharedInstance())
        
        // Report the incoming call to the system
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
            /*
                Only add incoming call to the app's list of calls if the call was allowed (i.e. there was no error)
                since calls may be "denied" for various legitimate reasons. See CXErrorCodeIncomingCallError.
             */
            if error == nil {
                let call = SpeakerboxCall(uuid: uuid)
                call.handle = handle

                self.callManager.addCall(call)
            }
            
            completion?(error as NSError?)
        }
    }
```